# Not get output in qt with opencv?

Tags: qt, opencv, ubuntu

i got output as ***empty terminal window*** while compiling following simple display an image program using qt with opencv in ubuntu.

code

```
    #include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
    #include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

    int main()

{

    cv::Mat image= cv::imread("img.jpg");
    cv::namedWindow("My Image");
    cv::imshow("My Image", image);
    cv::waitKey(5000);
    return 1;
}
```

give me solution?

thankyou

dhanash

Comment: I don't see and Qt thing here ?

Answer (score 0):

you need an other parameter to your `cv::imread` , and where is your core header ?? try this

```
  #include <opencv2/imgproc/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>

int main()

{

cv::Mat image= cv::imread("img.jpg",1);
 cv::imshow("My Image", image);
cv::waitKey(0);
return 0;
}
```